Help with Adapting a LaTeX Template for scrlttr2
I have a LaTeX template originally created for \documentclass{article} that displays CSV data in a table. I would like to adapt this template to work with the KOMA-Script class scrlttr2 since I need the layout for a formal letter.
Here’s the relevant part of my current article-based template:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,240mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,
}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\textbf{\today}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
    \section*{\centering Payment Table}
    \vspace{-0.7cm}
    \SetTblrTemplate{head,foot}{empty}
    \csvreader[
    generic collected table = longtblr,
    generic table options = {[
            rowhead = 1,
            colspec = {|l|c|r|c|c|},
            cell{2-Z}{Z} = {font=\bfseries},   
    ]},
    table head = \hline & \large \textbf{Invoice No.} &\large \textbf{Amount}&\large \textbf{Date} &\large \textbf{Status}\\\hline,
    late after line = \\\hline
    ]{path/to/myfile.csv}{InvoiceNo=\Re,Amount=\Be,Date=\Da,Status=\St}{
        \thecsvrow & \Re & \Be & \Da &
        \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{open}{\SetCell{fg=gray1}}{
            \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{paid}{\SetCell{fg=green5}}{
                \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{unpaid}{\SetCell{fg=red5}}{
                    \St
                }
            }
        }
    }
\end{document}

The table displays invoice numbers, amounts, dates, and status (e.g., "open", "paid", "unpaid"), with the font color changing based on the status.
Now, I want to adapt this template to \documentclass{scrlttr2} to fit a letter format while keeping the header and the table as they are. I’m looking for guidance on how to modify the template to work with the scrlttr2 class. If there are better suggestions or improvements, I’m happy to hear them.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Your question is quite unclear. What are your problems in moving from article to scrlttr2? Your example is also not working, even not if I add a speculative but suitable csv file.

First of all: There are mistakes in your example and also example csv data is missing. So your example is not working and the root of your problem is not really clear. Maybe already the mistakes in the shown code are the problem, maybe not. Because of this the answer is partly guessing what you want. The correction of the mistakes is marked by comments in the examples below. Please always try to show a minimal working example you've really tested. This should also show what you've tried.
The most simple would be to add package scrletter to your example and add a letter environment with \opening and \closing. Usage of fancyhdr needs to be remove, because scrletter uses package scrlayer-scrpage. But because you want to switch to a letter layout the change of page header and footer to letter-like once are also intended.
\begin{filecontents*}[force]{test.csv}
InvoiceNo,Amount,Date,Status
1,2,3,4
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,240mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,
}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{You\\There}
  \opening{Hi You!}
    \section*{\centering Payment Table}
    \SetTblrTemplate{head,foot}{empty}
    \csvreader[
    generic collected table = longtblr,
    generic table options = {{% <-- MISTAKE (must be `{` instead of `[`) FIXED
            rowhead = 1,
            colspec = {|l|c|r|c|c|},
            cell{2-Z}{Z} = {font=\bfseries},   
    }},% <-- MISTAKE (must be `}` instead of `]` fixed) FIXED
    table head = \hline & \large \textbf{Invoice No.} &\large \textbf{Amount}&\large \textbf{Date} &\large \textbf{Status}\\\hline,
    late after line = \\\hline
    ]{test.csv}{InvoiceNo=\Re,Amount=\Be,Date=\Da,Status=\St}{
        \thecsvrow & \Re & \Be & \Da &
        \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{open}{\SetCell{fg=gray1}}{
            \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{paid}{\SetCell{fg=green5}}{
                \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{unpaid}{\SetCell{fg=red5}}{
                    \St
                }
            }
        }
      }
  \closing{Regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}

As a next step you can replace usage of article + package scrletter, by usage of class scrletter, which is scrartcl + package scrletter:
\begin{filecontents*}[force]{test.csv}
InvoiceNo,Amount,Date,Status
1,2,3,4
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{scrletter}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,240mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,
}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\let\raggedsection\centering
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{You\\There}
  \opening{Hi You!}
    \section*{Payment Table}
    \SetTblrTemplate{head,foot}{empty}
    \csvreader[
    generic collected table = longtblr,
    generic table options = {{% <-- MISTAKE (must be `{` instead of `[`) FIXED
            rowhead = 1,
            colspec = {|l|c|r|c|c|},
            cell{2-Z}{Z} = {font=\bfseries},   
    }},% <-- MISTAKE (must be `}` instead of `]` fixed) FIXED
    table head = \hline & \large \textbf{Invoice No.} &\large \textbf{Amount}&\large \textbf{Date} &\large \textbf{Status}\\\hline,
    late after line = \\\hline
    ]{test.csv}{InvoiceNo=\Re,Amount=\Be,Date=\Da,Status=\St}{
        \thecsvrow & \Re & \Be & \Da &
        \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{open}{\SetCell{fg=gray1}}{
            \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{paid}{\SetCell{fg=green5}}{
                \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{unpaid}{\SetCell{fg=red5}}{
                    \St
                }
            }
        }
      }
  \closing{Regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}

Next you can replace usage of \section and make the whole thing more letter-like:
\begin{filecontents*}[force]{test.csv}
InvoiceNo,Amount,Date,Status
1,2,3,4
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{scrletter}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}% CHANGED (because example is not in German)
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \centering
  \LARGE\bfseries We-Break-Your-Arms-And-Legs-Encashment\\
  \normalsize \rule[1ex]{.667\linewidth}{1pt}\\
  But always try to smile at work
}
\setkomavar{subject}{Outstanding Invoices Reminder}
\setkomavar{customer}{0815}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Me}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Here}
\setkomavar{myref}{Joe}
\begin{letter}{You\\There}
  \opening{Hi You!}
  We would like to politely remind you that some invoices are still
  unpaid. Please refer to the following table for exact dates:
  \SetTblrTemplate{head,foot}{empty}
    \csvreader[
    generic collected table = longtblr,
    generic table options = {{% <-- MISTAKE (must be `{` instead of `[`) FIXED
            rowhead = 1,
            colspec = {|l|c|r|c|c|},
            cell{2-Z}{Z} = {font=\bfseries}, 
    }},% <-- MISTAKE (must be `}` instead of `]` fixed) FIXED
    table head = \hline & \large \textbf{Invoice No.} &\large \textbf{Amount}&\large \textbf{Date} &\large \textbf{Status}\\\hline,
    late after line = \\\hline
    ]{test.csv}{InvoiceNo=\Re,Amount=\Be,Date=\Da,Status=\St}{
        \thecsvrow & \Re & \Be & \Da &
        \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{open}{\SetCell{fg=gray1}}{
            \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{paid}{\SetCell{fg=green5}}{
                \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{unpaid}{\SetCell{fg=red5}}{
                    \St
                }
            }
        }
      }
  \closing{Regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}


Why does the same not work with scrlttr2 instead of scrletter?
Because tabularray needs counter table and floats like table are not defined in scrlttr2. One solution to make it work with scrlttr2 would be to define the missing counter (\newcounter{table}). But IMHO using scrletter instead of scrlttr2 is usually the better solution.
See the KOMA-Script manuals for more information about how to use scrletter and how this differs from using scrlttr2.
